Unable to get authorization in exchange of access token Spotify API
I am trying to get the User's playlist using Spotify API. I have got the access token by postman and
when i try to authorize it by exchanging the access token it doesnt authorize and instead it shows some error. Is there any problem in the code or the method used by me is incorrect? I am using javascript to get the data.
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const btoa = require('btoa');

const clientId = '6a6ff97f63df4b20a9d58a64991b520a';
const clientSecret = 'c6fb4a3c5ed64c8aa95bb85f7b859f77';
const redirectUri = 'https://localhost:3000';

const app = express();

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) =\> {
const code = req.query.code;
console.log('Received authorization code:', code);

    // Debugging logs for token exchange
    console.log('Exchanging authorization code for access token...');
    
    // Your code for exchanging code for access token
    
    // Debugging logs for access token
    console.log('Received access token:', accessToken);

if (!code) {
res.send('Authorization failed');
return;
}

    const authOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri
      })
    };

try {
const response = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', authOptions);
const data = await response.json();

    if (data.error) {
      res.send(`Error: ${data.error}`);
      return;
    }
    
    const accessToken = data.access_token;
    const refreshToken = data.refresh_token;
    
    // Save the tokens securely (e.g., in a database)
    console.log(`Access Token: ${accessToken}`);
    console.log(`Refresh Token: ${refreshToken}`);
    
    // Fetch user playlists
    const playlistsResponse = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    });
    const playlists = await playlistsResponse.json();
    
    res.json(playlists);

} catch (error) {
res.send(`Error: ${error.message}`);
}
});

app.listen(3000, () =\> {
console.log('Listening on port 8888');
console.log('Open this URL in a browser to authorize:');
console.log(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=playlist-read-private`);
});


your redirectUri is "https://localhost:3000" but your get code URL "https://localhost:3000/callback" both should be matched your dashboard's project setting in here

updated it but it shows INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

try this in here
